# Laravel 5.1 INSERT if record exists in another table

Tags: php, mysql, validation, laravel-5.1

Trying to get my first laravel applications finished, but since I'm quite new to it I cannot figure out a solution.
What I need is for user to be able to insert a row to table "Y" only if table "X" has a row with the value users is trying to save.
Quick exaple:

```
table X
----------------
name  |  idcode
----------------
john  |  12345(unique)
----------------
table Y
----------------
name  |  idcode
----------------
john  |  12345  <- user is able to save this row 
john  |  54321  <- user is not able to save this, since idcode does not
----------------   appear in table X
```

I'm able to do a check between two tables with unique index via request but that checks if idcode is in table X and if it is it won't let save in table Y. I could use and the same check but the other way around.
Has anyone had any experience with this?

Cheers

Comment: You could try something with select * from `tablex` where `idcode`=$idcode. What is causing you not to be able to save to tabley

Comment: thats the twist, users can only save to tabel y if table x has the same idcode value what users is trying to save.

Comment: something like **select * from x where idcode=?** and **if( ! $row)
{
die();
} else { insert row to table Y}**

Comment: Join the two table then validate it.?

Comment: they don't have to be joined. it feel to me like a simple thing to do but yet i cannot figure it out. table X acts like validation for table Y. admin can change table X content and user can only save rows to table Y if they exist in table X.

Comment: found a solution, ALTER TABLE tabely ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`idcode`) REFERENCES tabelx (`idcode`) simple FK helped

Answer (score 1):

Use this in validation rules `'idcode' => 'exists:y,idcode'`